# How do I upload an image to Cloudinary from behind a corporate proxy

Tags: javascript, next.js, proxy, cloudinary

My API uses the Cloudinary SDK to upload an image with the `uploader.upload()` method. But it times out.

I have the env variables set, `http_proxy`/`https_proxy`, that allow most everything else (such as the fetch API) to function.

As soon as I leave the corporate WiFi and thus the proxy, and remove all of the env variables, the upload works fine.

In this example, I have already set `api_proxy` in the `cloudinary.config()`, and send "`proxy`" with the options, but neither of those seem to do anything.

The GET method just confirms that there's nothing wrong with my API route.

```
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";


cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
  api_proxy: "http://corp-proxy:1234",
});

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello from upload" }, { status: 200 });
}

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { path } = await request.json();

  if (!path) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Image path is required" },
      { status: 400 }
    );
  }

  try {
    const options = {
      use_filename: true,
      unique_filename: false,
      overwrite: true,
      transformation: [{ width: 1000, height: 752, crop: "scale" }],
      proxy: "http://corp-proxy:1234",
    };

    //cloudinary result after upload
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(path, options);

    return NextResponse.json(result, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error uploading image", error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: error }, { status: 500 });
  }
```

One more note: although most https calls work fine after I set the environment variables and the npm config to use the proxy, Google OAuth is an example of another one that fails unless I leave the network. I don't know if there is a pattern there, but I can't think of any other config that would force these APIs to use the proxy

Comment: Hey there, 

It looks like you need to change the options to 'api_proxy'

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudinary_sdks#:~:text=for%20frontend%20SDKs.-,api_proxy,-1

Comment: There's two diferent parameters: "api_proxy" is for the global cloudinary config. "proxy" is an optional parameter on the "upload" method itself. I have both set.

I don't think "proxy" is needed in this case, sounds like it is for uploading from a remote URL, when I am trying to upload local files.